# Insert character at first and last position of a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to insert a character at the first "{" and last position "}" in a string variable. My code is

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";  
str = str.Substring(0, 1) + "{" + str.Substring(1, str.Length) + "}";
```

I expect as str = "{1,2,3,4,5,6}";

I am not getting the result. Please help me.

Comment: What do you expect as a result?

Comment: Do you mean `str = "{" + str + "}";`?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `Substring` at all: this should do the job:

```
str = "{" + str + "}";
```

Another common way of achieving the same result is with `string.Format`:

```
str = string.Format("{{{0}}}", str);
```

Note that `{` and `}` need to be doubled in order to be used around the `{0}` parameter designator as literal curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `+` operator:

```
str = "{" + str + "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

Here a program with [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

```
void Main()
{    
    string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";  
    str = String.Format("{{{0}}}", str);
    str.Dump();
}
```

Output will be;

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/8ONNKv)</kbd>.