# Getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I have a code given below. I am trying to convert it to an array of list.

```
  string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
  var newstring = new int[] {str};   //Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
```

Please help me. Thnaks in advance.

Comment: How about reading some c# tutorials? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937847/insert-character-at-first-and-last-position-of-a-string

Answer (score 5):

You can't just put any old string into an array initializer and expect it to just work as though you had typed that at compile time. You need to actually parse the string.

1. First, split it into an array of substrings using the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.
2. For each substring, parse it as an `int` using [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A little Linq can help here:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[] result = str.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't want to split the string.

Comment: @Jaan Do you want an array of `int`? If so, then you'll have to split it or do some relatively complicated looping. If not, then please be more clear on what exactly you do want. Note that `Split` doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: @Jaan: please watch kungfu panda. he does a perfect split for an almond cookie. ;)

Comment: @Jaan you don't want to split the string, you don't know c#. How do you expect it to be done?